# Jquery Fancybox not displaying on IE 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

I am using FancyBox to show larger versions of image thumbnails on a PHP application.

I am using a uniform CSS class name for all the thumbnails to trigger the Fancybox functions.

But when viewing the app on IE 7, only the first thumbnail actually triggers Fancybox, the rest of the thumbnails don't work.

What could be the problem, the links work correctly on Firefox and the other browsers.

Thanks

Comment: were not magicians :/ do you mind providing a link or some source if possible ?

Comment: I've got IE7 and it works fine for me from the example page: http://fancybox.net/home

Oh and I'm also a wizard, but there are some tachyons emanating from my hotpocket preventing me from remote viewing your code.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was arising from using one ID(not class name) for each of the links.

Thanx for your comments.